# Complete inner product space always has an orthonormal basis

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to understand inner product space. My text book says:

> A complete linear space with scalar product(not necessarily seperable) always has an orthonormal basis.

I looked up the definition of inner product space in wikipedia, it says:

> A complete space with an inner product is called a Hilbert space. An
>   incomplete space with an inner product is called a pre-Hilbert space.

But in order an inner product space to be a Hilbert space, it has to be seperable, right? I know Hilbert space has orthonormal basis. But does "non seperable Hilbert space" have an orthonormal basis? Could you please help me?

Comment: A Hilbert space doesn't have to be separable. The definition only requires that it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in a comment:

> A Hilbert space doesn't have to be separable. The definition only requires that it's complete. –  Svinepels Jan 14 at 17:31